# pyramid_handlers not working

Tags: python, pyramid, restful-architecture, akhet

I'm currently moving a project from Pylons 1.0 to Pyramid.

My problem so far is how to use restful routes in Pyramid. I'm currently using pyramid_handlers since it seemed like a good start. I'm using Akhet.

So here is the two important lines in my route:

```
config.add_handler("new_account", "/accounts/new", "sproci2.handlers.accounts:Accounts")
# or 
config.add_handler("new_account", "/accounts/new", "sproci2.handlers.accounts:Accounts", action="new")
```

My action:

```
@action(name="new_account", renderer='accounts/new.mako', request_method='GET')
```

The errors:

```
 TypeError: 'Accounts' object is not callable
 or
 ValueError: Could not convert view return value "{}" into a response Object.
```

Accounts... so far so good, it is easy to understand that pyramid_handlers doesn't seem to register normally or handle name as it should... that said in `request.matched_route`, I do have "new_account".

If I add "action='new'" in the route definition, it will find the function but it will not listen to the action definition. In other words, it will fail to find a renderer and expect a response object. The `request_method` parameter doesn't actually do anything yet, so removing it doesn't change any results.

In short, the `@action(name="..."` doesn't work. Pyramid fails to find the function by itself and if the function name is defined it fails to execute the action statement.

No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Correct way to do it.

```
config.add_handler("new_account", "/accounts/new", "sproci2.handlers.accounts:Accounts", action="new_account")
```

**EDIT**

`route_name` is probably going to get used by url generator functions. While action is the actual name in @action. As I understood, @action name was the route_name and not the action name. That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a call to `add_handler` needs an action pattern. So that's either adding `{action}` to the url pattern, or setting `action=` as an argument. Those actions must match the names defined in `@action` decorators. In your example, you named the action `new_account`, yet you called `add_handler` with an action of `new`. Thus they aren't properly connected.

Comment: I was expecting a different behaviour.. the name in action would be the route that must match and not the action that must match.. It probably got in the right function new since it is how I called it. But was expecting a ResponseObject since the "new" wasn't defined in any @action...  That makes a lot of sense now.